# Clonar um construtor nativo do javascript sem alterar o original

Tags: javascript, construtor

Estou tentando criar uma biblioteca pessoal, onde a ideia original era estender os objetos nativos do javascript com várias funções úteis. Após ler um pouco, acabei me convencendo que estender objetos nativos não é exatamente uma boa ideia, então tive a ideia de criar novos construtores exatamente iguais aos construtores nativos, e então adicionar os métodos neles, para não afetar os originais. A ideia seria algo assim:

```
var MyDate = Date;
MyDate.prototype.teste = function() {
    console.log('teste');
};

var a = new MyDate();
var b = new Date();
```

Funciona bem, só que o problema é que...

```
a.teste() // 'teste'
b.teste() // 'teste'
```

Entendi que isso ocorre por que na verdade `MyDate` se tornou apenas uma referencia para `Date`, e não um novo construtor, mas neste caso, como consigo "clonar" um construtor completamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer extender as classes nativas do javascript você deve dar uma olhada nas palavras-chave [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) e [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) e o conceito de [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class).

```js
//Extende a classe Date sem interferir com a classe base
class MyDate extends Date {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  // Adiciona um método na declaração de classe
  foo() {
    console.log('Método foo!');
  }

}

// adiciona o método teste via protótipo como no exemplo.
MyDate.prototype.teste = function() {
  console.log('teste');
};

var aDate = new MyDate();
var bDate = new Date();
aDate.teste(); // > "teste"
aDate.foo(); // > "Método foo!"
try {
  bDate.teste(); // > Error: bDate.teste is not a function
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
};
try {
  bDate.foo(); // > Error: bDate.foo is not a function
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
};
```

## Edit:

Também é possível extender uma classe nativa usando [funções construtoras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454788/137387) aplicando o método [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) para invocar os construtores das superclasses.

O mesmo exemplo anterior mas desta vez usando funções construtoras:

```js
   
//Mydate é uma função construtora cujo os argumentos correspondem
//ao constructor sobrecarregado Date(arg1:[ano|valor|dataString|undefined], mês, dia, hora, minuto, segundo, milissegundo);
const MyDate = function(arg1, mês, dia, hora, minuto, segundo, milissegundo) {
  //Extende a classe MyDate chamando o constructor da superclasse Date a this
  Date.call(this, ...arguments);
  // Adiciona um método na declaração de classe
  this.foo = function() {
    console.log('Método foo!');
  }
}

// adiciona o método teste via protótipo como no exemplo.
MyDate.prototype.teste = function() {
  console.log('teste');
};

var aDate = new MyDate();
var bDate = new Date();
aDate.teste(); // > "teste"
aDate.foo(); // > "Método foo!"
try {
  bDate.teste(); // > Error: bDate.teste is not a function
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
};
try {
  bDate.foo(); // > Error: bDate.foo is not a function
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
};
```