# Diferença entre função construtora e função que retorna objeto literal

Tags: javascript, funções, característica-linguagem, objetos, construtor

Qual a diferença prática entre eu criar uma função construtora desta forma:

```
function construtora (nome, sobrenome) {
    this.nome = nome
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome
}
```

Ou desta forma:

```
function construtora (nome, sobrenome) {
    let obj = {}
    
    obj.nome = nome
    obj.sobrenom = sobrenome
    
    return obj
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual é a diferença entre criar um objeto a partir da forma literal ou a partir de uma função construtora?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445939/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-criar-um-objeto-a-partir-da-forma-literal-ou-a-partir-d)

Answer (score 4):

No seu primeiro exemplo, você têm uma função que funciona como construtura (*constructor function*), que retorna uma nova instância de objeto se você chamá-la utilizando o operador `new`. Assim:

```js
function construtora(nome, sobrenome) {
  this.nome = nome;
  this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
}

const instance = new construtora('John', 'Doe');
console.log(instance);
```

Como você não especificou na resposta se está usando o `new` ou não, acho pertinente falar que se você simplesmente invocar a função, sem utilizar o operador [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), um objeto não será retornado. A chamada simplesmente retornará `undefined`:

```js
function construtora(nome, sobrenome) {
  this.nome = nome;
  this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
}

const instance = construtora('John', 'Doe');
console.log(instance); // undefined
```

A partir do ECMAScript 2015 (vulgo ES6), esse padrão "prototípico" clássico para atingir um certo tipo de "orientação a objetos" no JavaScript foi sendo menos usado, uma vez que a construção `class` foi introduzida. Mas não se engane, pois [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) não passa de mero açúcar sintático para essa antiga abordagem prototípica.

---

Já no seu segundo exemplo, não diria que a função (`construtora`) é, de fato, uma função construtora. Você está criando um tipo de função fábrica (*factory function*), por que você cria um objeto literal e o retorna. Vale dizer que nos dois casos um objeto está sendo criado, mas há uma sutil diferença a qual eu entro em mais detalhes **[nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445939/69296)**.

De forma resumida (leia a pergunta [referida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445939/69296) para saber mais), nesse segundo exemplo, você está criando um objeto literal (o que não é o caso no primeiro exemplo). Desse modo, se você verificar, a forma como os objetos foram construídas é diferente e, nesse caso, os construtores também. Veja:

```js
function construtora1(nome, sobrenome) {
  this.nome = nome;
  this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
}

function construtora2(nome, sobrenome) {
  let obj = {};
  obj.nome = nome;
  obj.sobrenom = sobrenome;
  return obj;
}

const instance = new construtora1('John', 'Doe');
const obj = construtora2('Luiz', 'Felipe');

console.log(instance);
console.log(obj);

console.log(instance.constructor.name); // "construtora1"
console.log(obj.constructor.name); // "Object"
```

Note que, apesar das propriedade próprias (*own properties*) dos objetos `instance` e `obj` serem as mesmas, os construtores são diferentes, o que também indica uma diferente [cadeia de protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/69296).

---

A título de preferência, eu pessoalmente considero o nome da função do primeiro exemplo `construtora` correto, já que a função está construindo um objeto (`contrutora` é o construtor do objeto se este tiver sido criado através do operador `new`).

No entanto, o nome da função (`construtora`) do segundo exemplo não me parece tão preciso, já que não é a função (`construtora`) que constrói o objeto, mas sim `Object`. Vale lembrar que, internamente, quando você cria objetos literais, eles são *construídos* a partir de [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Do ponto e vista semântico e interno da linguagem, há a diferença de que, quando se chama uma função sem o operador `new`, a propriedade interna `[[Call]]` é invocada. Quando a função é chamada utilizando o operador `new`, a propriedade interna `[[Construct]]` é chamada. Consulte [esta tabela](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#table-6) para saber mais.

A própria especificação (na tabela referida) refere-se às funções que implementam `[[Call]]` como "*callable*" e às funções que implementam `[[Construct]]` como "*constructors*". Vale salientar que toda *constructor function* é, também, *callable*.

---

<sup>Não tem a ver com a pergunta, mas note que coloquei ponto e vírgula no final de cada *statement*. Pode parecer "frescura", mas criei esse hábito para evitar [algumas situações bizarras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432960/69296) que podem ocorrer se você não utilizar o ponto e vírgula em todas as linhas (veja mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3341/69296)).</sup>