# Dúvida sobre o Number.isInteger() em JS. Number é um objeto ou função?

Tags: javascript, funções, objetos

`Number` seria uma função ou objeto?

Meu professor disse que tudo no JavaScript pode ser visto como função (até mesmo os objetos) e isso me confundiu um pouco. O mesmo me falou que `Number` seria um objeto global encapsulado, mas para termos um objeto é necessário que ele seja instanciado a partir de uma classe, então como isso é possível?

Ele apenas jogou o seguinte código: `console.log(Number.isInteger(variavelX))` de forma direta sem instanciar o `Number`. Então, pensei que `Number` fosse um objeto e que `isInteger()` fosse um método de sua classe, mas ele nem ao menos instanciou tal objeto. Então, como posso entender este conceito?

Comment: Leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas) e leia também [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta?cb=1)

Comment: Removi a segunda pergunta sobre "objeto global encapsulado" porque a ideia do site é focar cada pergunta em um assunto específico. Se quiser, pode abrir outra pergunta sobre isso (não esquecendo de pesquisar antes no site se já existe alguma pergunta sobre o assunto)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *`Number` é um objeto ou função?*

Ambos.

---

Tecnicamente falando, `Number` é uma função:

```js
console.log(typeof Number); // function
```

Mas é uma ["função construtora"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454788/112052), que permite que se crie instâncias através do operador `new`.

Só que [funções também são objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), e qualquer objeto pode ter funções "acopladas" a ele:

```js
// um objeto qualquer
let obj = { id: 1, nome: 'Fulano' };
// definir uma propriedade que é uma função
obj.funcao = function() { console.log('oi') };
// chamar a função
obj.funcao(); // oi
```

Sendo assim, nada impede que se faça o mesmo com uma função:

```js
function Abc() {
    // função faz algo...
}

Abc.fazOutraCoisa = function(n) {
    console.log(n);
}
Abc.fazOutraCoisa(20); // 20
```

Repare que não preciso criar uma instância de `Abc` para usar a função `fazOutraCoisa`. Pois ela é um atributo da própria função `Abc`. Da mesma forma que `isInteger` é uma função de `Number` (da própria função `Number`, não das suas instâncias, por isso não precisa instanciar nada para usá-la).

No caso da função ser construtora, não deixa de ser uma forma de simular os métodos estáticos de outras linguagens. Tanto que `isInteger` é listado na [seção de "métodos estáticos" de `Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Static_methods).

---

> "*Mas achei que fosse uma classe*"

No fundo, [JavaScript não tem classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108559/112052). Mesmo que [a versão atual da linguagem suporte o `class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), ele é só um açúcar sintático para criar a função construtora:

```js
class Abc {
    constructor(n) {
        this.valor = n;
    }

    metodo() {
        console.log(this.valor);
    }

    static metodoEstatico() {
        console.log(this.valor); // undefined, pois a função/classe Abc não tem o atributo "valor"
    }
}

// Abc é uma função!
console.log(typeof Abc); // function

let a = new Abc(10);
a.metodo(); // 10
Abc.metodoEstatico(); // undefined
```

O código acima é equivalente a esse:

```js
function Abc(n){
    this.valor = n;

    this.metodo = function() {
        console.log(this.valor);
    }
}

Abc.metodoEstatico = function() {
    console.log(this.valor); // undefined, pois a função/classe Abc não tem o atributo "valor"
}

console.log(typeof Abc); // function
let a = new Abc(10);
a.metodo(); // 10
Abc.metodoEstatico(); // undefined
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação! Sanou todas as minhas dúvidas e com certeza já foi para as minhas anotações :)

Answer (score 6):

> `Number` seria uma função ou objeto?

TL;DR: É uma função construtora (e, portanto, um objeto também, saiba mais [na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) e na pergunta [Por que Arrays e Funções são Objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/480170/69296)). Quando chamada, retorna um primitivo numérico e, quando instanciada, retorna um objeto ("instância") `Number`. Possui, também, métodos e propriedades próprios — "estáticos" — que não serão passados aos primitivos e objetos construídos (como `isInteger`) e métodos e propriedades em seu protótipo que serão passados aos primitivos e objetos construídos (como `toFixed`).

---

#### Breve história dos primitivos

É incorreto afirmar que, no JavaScript, tudo é função. Provavelmente houve um engano, já que é comum afirmar-se que *tudo no JavaScript é um objeto*.

Mas nem  essa última afirmação é verdadeira, já que os *primitivos* não são, de fato, objetos. Todos os outros valores são objetos. Os primitivos são `undefined`, `null`, `boolean`, `number`, `bigint`, `string` e `symbol`.

Existem algumas diferenças, como o fato de que primitivos são passados por valor e objetos, por referência. Mas há, entre primitivos e objetos, uma notável semelhança: ambos podem possuir *propriedades*. Isso cria a confusão, pois algumas pessoas podem (erroneamente!) pensar que, por possuirem propriedades, ambos se tratam de objetos.

Vale notar que as *propriedades* (e métodos) dos primitivos vêm de funções construtoras associadas ao tipo primitivo. Desse modo:

- Primitivos do tipo `number` associam-se ao construtor [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number);
- Primitivos do tipo `string` associam-se ao construtor [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String);
- E o mesmo para `boolean` ([`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)), `bigint` ([`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)) e `symbol` ([`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)).

Essas associações dão, aos primitivos, suas propriedades e métodos. Como, por exemplo, o método [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), que o construtor `Number` oferece a todos os primitivos do tipo `number`. Ou a propriedade [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) que `string`s  possuem. Esse assunto é um pouco mais avançado e, para entender melhor, procure estudar sobre a [cadeia de protótipos em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript).

Somente os primitivos `null` e `undefined` *não* possuem essa associação e, portanto, também não possuem nenhuma propriedade e nenhum método.

#### E construtores, como `Number`?

Com a breve explicação acima, podemos concluir que, embora `number` seja um primitivo, `Number` é o **construtor** associado a todos os primitivos do tipo `number`. Assim, diz-se que `Number` é, de fato, uma função construtora — nesse caso, associada ao primitivo `number`.

Note, na seção acima, que não falei em nenhum momento de funções como primitivos ou objetos. Isso porque, de certo modo, elas não são nem primitivos e nem objetos. A [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_and_Structure_types) classifica funções e objetos como "tipos estruturais" da linguagem.

Vale lembrar que, assim como os objetos, as funções também têm propriedades, métodos e são passíveis de modificações. Em constraste, primitivos podem ter propriedades, métodos, mas são imutáveis.

De certo modo, `Number` (e as outras funções construtoras) permitem a construção do seu primitivo associado quando aplicadas (invocadas):

```js
// Aplicação da função construtora:
const myConstructedNumberPrimitive = Number('123');

console.log(
  myConstructedNumberPrimitive,
  typeof myConstructedNumberPrimitive
); // 123 number
```

```js
// Utilização da função construtora para instanciação de um objeto:
//                                 ↓↓↓
const myInstantiatedNumberObject = new Number('123');

console.log(
  myInstantiatedNumberObject,
  typeof myInstantiatedNumberObject
); // Number {123} object
```

<sup>No console do *snippet* do StackOverflow, aparece um "objeto vazio" (`{}`). Utilize o [console do navegador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFymt.png) para inspecionar que se trata, evidentemente, de um objeto instanciado a partir do construtor `Number`.</sup>

A utilização do `new` é explicada com mais sutileza [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454788/112052).

Em suma:

- `Number` é uma função construtora que permite a criação de **primitivos**, se aplicada; ou permite a instanciação de **objetos**, se o operador `new` for utilizado. Esses dois casos foram demonstrados acima.

Como primitivos e objetos, as funções também podem possuir propriedades ou métodos. Assim, `isInteger` é um método de `Number`.

Note que `isInteger`, por ser um método de `Number`, não será disponível como método do primitivo `number` (retornado pela aplicação da construtora) ou dos objetos (retornados pela instanciação da construtora). Os métodos "passados" para baixo devem estar no protótipo de `Number`.

Veja a diferença:

```js
console.log(typeof Number.isInteger); // (function) Disponível. Propriedade do construtor `Number`.
console.log(typeof Number.toFixed); //  (undefined) Indisponível. Propriedade do protótipo.

console.log(typeof (1).isInteger); // (undefined). Indisponível. É propriedade do construtor, mas não do primitivo.
console.log(typeof (1).toFixed); //    (function). Disponível. É propriedade, trazida do protótipo do construtor.

// Mostra os métodos e propriedades da função construtora `Number`.
// Estes métodos e propriedades não serão passados ao primitivo e
// objetos construídos por este construtor.
console.log(
  'Propriedades do construtor:',
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number)
);

// Mostra os métodos e propriedades do protótipo da função construtora `Number`.
// São estes métodos e propriedades que serão passados ao primitivo e
// objetos construídos por este construtor.
console.log(
  'Propriedades do protótipo do construtor:',
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number.prototype)
);
```

Comment: Obrigado por complementar a resposta do colega acima! Foi de suma importância e já está nas minhas anotações.