# Por que a alteração de uma variável em uma função não reflete na própria variável passada?

Tags: javascript, funções

```js
let a = 2;

let change = (val) => {
  val = 3;
}

change(a);
console.log(a);
```

Eu esperava que o valor de `a` fosse 3, mas na verdade é 2. Por quê?

Comment: pq vc passou o valor (by val)  da variável para a function, e não a variável (by reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O motivo está descrito na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions):

> *Primitive parameters (such as a number) are passed to functions **by value**; the value is passed to the function, but if the function changes the value of the parameter, **this change is not reflected globally or in the calling function**.*

Ou seja, parâmetros [primitivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/474567/112052) (como um número) são passados para funções **por valor**: isso quer dizer que o valor é passado para a função, mas se a função mudar o valor do parâmetro, esta mudança não se reflete fora dela.

Isso quer dizer que esta função:

```
function change(val) {
    val = 3;
}
```

muda o valor do parâmetro `val`, mas esta mudança não se reflete fora da função.

> Aliás, uma função criada com a palavra-chave `function` nem sempre é equivalente à *arrow function* (que é a sintaxe que você usou). Claro que em muitos casos "funcionará" da mesma forma, mas [existem diferenças importantes entre essas duas opções](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). <sup><sub>*Tenho visto muita gente usando arrow function sem pensar, achando que é o único jeito (ou o "jeito moderno") de declarar uma função, mas para casos como o seu, não há ganho nenhum em usá-las, e eu prefiro criar uma `function` normal mesmo.*</sub></sup>

---

E faz sentido que seja assim. Por exemplo, eu posso chamar a função desta forma:

```
change(10);
```

Passei o valor diretamente, sem nenhuma variável externa à função. Se a função mudasse o valor que está fora dela, ao fazer `val = 3`, o que exatamente seria mudado? O `10`? Não faz sentido.

E se eu chamasse assim?

```
change(outraFuncao() * 10 + 5);
```

Supondo que `outraFuncao` é uma função que retorna algum valor, e eu ainda multiplico-o por 10 e somo 5, e o resultado é passado para `change`. Se a função `change` mudasse o valor que está fora dela, o que exatamente seria alterado?

Ou seja, na minha humilde opinião, não faz sentido que a atribuição feita dentro da função reflita fora dela.

---

Resumindo, se você faz:

```
function change(val) {
    val = 3;
}

let a = 2;
change(a);
```

O valor de `a` é copiado para o parâmetro `val`. Dentro da função, `val` tem seu valor alterado, mas esta alteração não reflete em `a` (já que `val` é apenas uma cópia do valor de `a`). Quando a função encerra sua execução, `val` é descartada (pois ela só existe dentro da função). E `a` segue com seu valor inalterado.

---

Por fim, é interessante conhecer os conceitos de [passagem por valor e por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59437/112052) para entender melhor o que acontece. E para se aprofundar especificamente no JavaScript, [leia aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000).

Answer (score 4):

E eu devolvo a pergunta, por que acha que que `a` deveria ser 3 se em nenhum momento você mudou seu valor?

Sabe [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) Então tem um valor armazenado nela, se você não muda o valor da variável, como esse valor deveria mudar automaticamente?

É bom perguntar, mas precisa partir de premissas corretas.

Você tem duas variáveis, uma é `a` que nunca foi alterada. E tem `val` que existe dentro de uma função que é alterada, mas logo depois seu valor é descartado. `val` só existe dentro da função.

Quando você chama uma função e passa um [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) está atribuindo o valor desse argumento para a variável declarada como um parâmetro. Na chamada da função seria o mesmo que fazer:

```
val = a;
```

`val` recebe o valor que tinha em `a`, mas `val` não passa ser `a`. Há uma cópia de valor.

Vou fazer outra pergunta. Por que fez:

```
let change = (val) => {
    val = 3;
}
```

Quando poderia ter feito:

```
function change(val) {
    val = 3;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/Variable.js).

Sabe as implicações de cada um? Faça o simples até ter necessidade de fazer o complexo.