# Como um valor pode ser invocado (como uma função) ao mesmo tempo em que contém propriedades (como um objeto) em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, funções, característica-linguagem, objetos

Fiquei com uma dúvida referente a estrutura do Express.

Como o Express consegue ser invocado, como em `express()`, mas também consegue ter em sua estrutura acesso à propriedade Router, por exemplo?

Não sei se ficou clara minha dúvida, então vou tentar exemplificar. Para criar uma estrutura com acesso a um método de nome `Router`, por exemplo, basta criar um objeto e definir uma propriedade para ele com nome `Router` e a ela atribuir uma função, exemplo:

```
var express = {
    Router: () => { console.log("Acessou o router"); }
};
```

No exemplo acima, eu conseguiria acessar a propriedade `Router` facilmente, tal como em `express.Router()`.

O problema é que da forma acima não seria possível invocar o objeto Express como em `express()`, visto que ele é um objeto. Se eu tentar fazer como no exemplo abaixo, dá erro:

```
var express = {
    (): () => { console.log("Iniciou o express"); },
    Router: () => { console.log("Acessou o Router"); }
};
```

Não preciso entender especificamente como o Express faz, mas apenas gostaria de entender como isso seria possível, visto que ao meu ver não teria possibilidade de um objeto funcionar com chamadas diretas de função.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/474549/112052 (explica que toda função também é um objeto e por isso pode ter propriedades)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em JavaScript, toda função é um objeto.

E é bem simples, fugindo da formalidade da linguagem, provar isso. Veja:

```
function x() {}
x instanceof Object; //-> true
```

Mais detalhadamente, "objetos função" implementam uma propriedade interna a qual a especificação refere como [`[[Call]]`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist). Todo objeto em JavaScript que possui essa propriedade interna é uma função e, portanto, pode ser invocado.

Como funções são objetos, torna-se possível anexar qualquer propriedade em uma função. Embora não seja possível utilizar a notação literal de objetos para definir o `[[Call]]` de uma função (tal como a pergunta sugere), pode-se criar a função e, posteriormente, atribuir as propriedades desejadas.

No caso do Express, seria algo como:

```
function express() {
  // return new express instance
}

express.Router = function() {
  // return new router instance
};
```

Se várias propriedades haverem de ser adicionadas, pode-se utilizar `Object.assign`, que facilita a atribuição:

```
function express() {
  // return new express instance
}

Object.assign(express, {
  Router: function() {
    // return new router instance
  }
});
```

---

Um pouco relacionado: [Por que Arrays e Funções são Objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/480169/69296).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação. Uma última dúvida que tenho, claro, sem querer abusar da boa vontade, mas porque eu preciso instanciar diretamente o express para que ele funcione? talvez a pergunta seja idiota, mas eu não consegui ver sentido na criação de uma instancia do express, visto que se eu tenho acesso a propriedade Router sem instanciar, porque eu não poderia ter acesso a propriedade listen também sem instanciar o express de forma direta?. Tipo, porque esse funciona: const router  = express.Router(); mas esse não: const app  = express.listen("porta", ()=>{});

Comment: Não posso responder isso de forma categórica (já que foi uma opção de design de API do criador do Express), mas eu acho que isso é útil para que várias instâncias do Express possam ser criadas e usadas ao mesmo tempo. Ter só uma instância já fornecida poderia ser limitador em alguns cenários. O objeto criado por `Router` e a instância do `express` são coisas diferentes. A propriedade `listen` está nas _instâncias_ criadas por `express()`, e não no próprio objeto (função) `express`.